# Getting permission denied error while executing ./start-dfs.sh for a single node hadoop cluster, trying on CentOS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

```
[dsawale@localhost sbin]$ ./start-dfs.sh 
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [localhost.localdomain]
localhost.localdomain: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
2020-03-05 13:17:11,502 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Comment: Did u resolve this? After a while of not using my laptop this came. Must be some expiry aspect. So, looking into what it means.

Answer (score 0):

This error is commonly attributed to the fact that you've not created and distributed passwordless SSH keys.

You'll also want to remove `localhost.localdomain` from /etc/hosts

Comment: So, recently I booted my linux pc, centos 8. I got this error now all of a sudden and hav regenned. Does not resolve it. Why does this all of a sudden occur out of the blue when working for a year? Any input welcome.

Comment: @thebluephantom Maybe OpenSSH / OpenSSL got upgraded? I'm not aware of an expiration setting on SSH keys, at least not with the keygen command that Hadoop docs have

Comment: There is the upgrade option of centos , but indeed a little puzzled here. thx anyway.